# How can I install vmargin.sty?

Tags: installing

Can someone help me how to install an additional file in LaTeX? I was trying to run mine and it is telling me that the file `vmargin.sty` is not found.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question is very vague. And I don't think that `vmargin` should really used any longer. Use the `geometry` package for such changes, but this depends on the code you're actually using...

Comment: You can use the *geometry* package instead, is the standard now.

Comment: I've edited the title of your question to be a bit more meaningful. The majority of questions are about LaTeX and all of them are asking for assistance, so your original subject was not terribly helpful. Is there some particular reason you need `vmargin`? Which distribution do you use? TeX Live includes `vmargin.sty` by default, for instance, and I assume MikTeX has it also. So *if* you really need this package for some reason, probably you should use your package manager, but it is hard to say without more details. Certainly `geometry` is preferable, as @ChristianHupfer says.

Comment: @cfr: A (much) better title, indeed

Comment: You can download vmargin.sty from [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/vmargin) and put it into the same directory as your document.

Comment: This depends on your TeX distribution. However, I agree with Christian that `vmargin` should be avoided, as it makes the document not compatible with several useful packages.

Comment: If you by ny chance ant to use a special thesis template that requires `vmargin` ... listen to the hints, `vmargin` is out of date and so is the template. It should not be used anymore as it causes lots of trouble.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments.

Comment: I had the same question and here's the answer for kde neon (It's Ubuntu based so the solution should work for regular Ubuntu too). First download the files of the package from [this link](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/vmargin). Then open a terminal in the directory of the downloaded files and do `tex vmargin.ins` which will make a file `vmargin.sty`. You can then copy that file over to the directory of the document. Why is the question closed? The question is about installing a certain package and has an answer that wasn't so easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu, the file is included in the package `texlive-latex-extra`.

To locate other files in Ubuntu packages "Search the contents of packages" at http://packages.ubuntu.com/ can be very helpful.

For other systems, installation will be different, but this hint may be helpful for certain people.